# Rails-API + Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I am working on an application that is built on `rails-api` and is using `authlogic` to handle user authentication.

When I post to `UserSessions`, the user is authenticated and the correct user is updated and returned. The `user_credentials` cookie is being set and when I look at the request headers, I can see that the correct cookie is being passed.

The issue I am seeing is that the `current_user_session` and `current_user methods` are not being set.

I am using the pretty standard current_user_session and current_user methods.

```
def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end

def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
end
```

Answer (score 0):

These are my non-researched findings from tinkering with rails-api together with auth-logic (so, no useful links and possible I've misunderstood the underlying causes)

By using rails-api, you have to *enable* a lot of the middleware, in my case specifically `ActionDispatch::Cookies` and `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore`.

Look at the `POST` request response, and check if there is a header `Set-Cookie`. If not, you're missing the middleware that generates that header automatically.

Try to comment out `rails-api` in your Gemfile and look at the differences in the output of

```
rake middleware
```

I hope this helps, and if I get the time to dive deeper into this issue, I hope to remember to update this post.